# How do I show just the legend for geom_point when using both geom_point and geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find that the combination of line and point in the legend to be a little muddled and can be difficult to read, especially when colour reports are printed in black and white. I'd like to do a line chart with different shape points however just have the legend show the point shapes without the line through them.

Some data and code:

```
library (tidyr)
library (ggplot2)

year <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014)
x <- c(50, 49, 50, 53, 52)
y <- c(33, 33, 32, 30, 26)

df <- data.frame (year, x, y) %>%
  gather (group, value, x:y)

ggplot (df, aes (x = year, y = value, colour = group)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_line(aes(group=group), size=1.5) + 
  geom_point(size=6, aes (shape = group)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(15, 16, 17, 18))
```

Gives me this:

[image]

I'd like the legend to look more like this:

[image]

Comment: You have duplicate `geom_line` calls. Remove the first one and just do: `geom_line(aes(group=group), size=1.5, show_guide=FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks - it was the `show_guide - FALSE` I was missing.